# Reading a text file line by line

Tags: powershell, scripting, line

I'm new to power shell and can't seem to get this script correct.

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$users = Get-Content '\\fssrv\homeshares$\fMunoz00\Desktop\users.txt'
$users1 = Get-Content '\\fssrv\homeshares$\fMunoz00\Desktop\users1.txt'
$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("\\Fssrv\homeshares$\$users1\$users.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "\\asrv1\users\$users"
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Every time it goes to "users.txt" it tries to read it as a complete file. Instead i would like for it to read as followed:

```
User1

User2

User3
```

I just can't seem to get this to work.

RE-EDIT:

What I’m trying to accomplish:

We went from one storage server to a new storage server.

ASRV1 to FSSRV

I want to create a shortcut from asrv1 to fssrv. Along with the upgrade we are also changing domains and changing everyone windows user names.

For example my user name was fMunoz and it was changed to fMunoz00.

I want to pull from a text file > users.txt with all the old usernames, and create shortcuts to the new user names storage file those users names are in a txt file called users1.txt.

Comment: What are some expected values of `$Shortcut.TargetPath`? What are the expected, expanded value(s) of some of these other expanded strings that are being constructed? It's easier to picture potential solutions when we don't have to interpolate what those look like from what's currently there.

Comment: I'm needing (1) shortcut created per folder. For example user: fmunoz is located at \\asrv1\users\fmunoz, and i want to create a shortcut of that directory to \\fssrv\homeshares$\fmunoz00\fmunoz.lnk with the "fmunoz" name.

Comment: Is the remote path enumerable? If so you might be able to avoid the need to read directories from a text file and simply query the target filesystem for a list of folders

Comment: Both directories can be accessed from my computer. One directory is on a complete different domain name but there is a trust between both of the domains and i can access the directories. Can you please elaborate more on how i can accomplish this please, i appreciate all your help. thanks.

Comment: I **really** believe you should think this one over again, because as I read from tghe `RE-EDIT`, there are two separate files where the first contains _old_ usernames and the second one contains the _new_ names. There is absolutely no guarantee these names actually match, so you could easily end up with a user `fMunoz` being renamed/connected to new name `jDoe00`. I'd advise to create a CSV file with two columns `OldName` and `NewName` so you can see the names match. Then read this one file once and copy the shortcuts to the correct user.

Comment: Theo... I have gone ahead and created an excel sheet with column A being my old usernames and Column B being my new user names. How should the code look to make this a possibility? Can you show me an example so i can modify it to work for me. I really appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request, you want to create shortcuts in each home directory of the people in `Users1.txt`

This means you will need to complete multiple `ForEach` loops to cycle through both txt files.

```
$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell
$users = Get-Content '\\fssrv\homeshares$\fMunoz00\Desktop\users.txt'
$users1 = Get-Content '\\fssrv\homeshares$\fMunoz00\Desktop\users1.txt'

# For every line in $users1, Do something
Foreach($User in $users1) {
    # For every line in $users, Do something
    Foreach($Name in $users) {
        $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("\\Fssrv\homeshares$\$User\$Name.lnk")
        $Shortcut.TargetPath = "\\asrv1\users\$Name"
        $Shortcut.Save()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm needing (1) shortcut created per folder. For example user: fmunoz is located at \\asrv1\users\fmunoz, and i want to create a shortcut of that directory to \\fssrv\homeshares$\fmunoz00\fmunoz.lnk with the "fmunoz" name.

Comment: Drew please help, i feel you got me very close to figuring this code out. Please help me finish it. I really appreciate your help. thank you.

Comment: Are all of the folders going to be named `[user]00`?

Comment: No. The name of the created shortcut will not include 00. Example \\asrv1\users\%username%.  Will be copied over as a shortcut to \\fssrv\homeshares\fmunoz00\%username%... thank you so much for your continued help

Comment: Still having trouble understanding what you are trying to have created. Please edit your answer to include a sample content of both `Users1.txt` and `Users.txt`.

Comment: Drew please see my re-edit. I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for helping me.

I came up with a different solution for my problem. The way i fixed this issue was by creating an excel sheet w/ 2 columns.

OLD USERS | NEW USERS

I then created a mail merge using microsoft word. Then i continued with the following code in powershell to start my loop:

$WshShell = New-Object -comObject WScript.Shell

Once my loop was started with i then utilized mail merge to take <> from the excel sheet and replaced it with the insert it into my code. Also took <> and did the same.

$Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut("\Fssrv\homeshares$\«New_Users»\«Old_Users»_Z Drive.lnk")
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "\asrv1\users\«Old_Users»"
$Shortcut.Save()

I hope this can help anyone else trying to accomplish something similar.

Yet again, Thanks & Good Luck...